# I'm a bioinfo software developer, and I would like to use bioinformatics SE as the main platform for Q&A

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm an author of bioinformatic software and I would like to use this stackexchange as the main platform for questions and answers (indicate this in the README). The software is recent and there is no tag yet.

- Is it appropriate to redirect users to this SE?
- Wouldn't that be considered an inappropriate self-advertisement
- There is no tag at the moment. So I cannot subscribe. What is the best way?

  1. Ask one of the users to ask here.
  2. Create a single Q & A myself.
  3. Create a tag before there are real questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general it's fine to use SE as an official support forum. Snakemake currently uses stackoverflow for that purpose as well (though I'm not sure how official that is). You have quite a bit of reputation, so I think you can create a tag (if not, just ping me and mention what you'd like the tag to be). I don't think you need to worry about self-advertisement, there as no consensus that that was a problem here and I personally would find it incredibly annoying to have to mention that on an answer dealing with any software I've contributed to.

Comment: Devon, could you then please create a tag called [godon](https://bitbucket.org/Davydov/godon/)? I don't seem to have the permission. If you create a stub I can update the description of the tag.

Comment: Done: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/godon Please suggest some content for that tag :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Devon. I suggested a tag description some time ago, but it was not approved yet.