# Citing BioSE as algorithm support

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

I am seeking permission to cite https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com as  support for a new algorithm to identify specific mutations across large sequence databases. There isn't an equivalent calculation. The code is OOP/AOP Python with extensive parallelisation and optimisation.

In the first instance the algorithm is released via Docker in < 2 months and more widely through mainstream distribution channels thereafter.

---

Here's the historic response. I would assume this agreement  remains active.

[I'm a bioinfo software developer, and I would like to use bioinformatics SE as the main platform for Q&A](https://bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240/im-a-bioinfo-software-developer-and-i-would-like-to-use-bioinformatics-se-as-t/241#241)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is fine. Thanks for asking.

Comment: Huge thanks @gringer much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I am happy with this - it sounds like a relevant piece of software and the more relevant high-quality questions that we have the expertise to answer the better!

Comment: Thanks for your support and approval @user438383 democracy is good.